# Why a variable value deletes in js file. when I open jquery fancy box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two .js files and an HTML. I intialize a value to a variable from one .js file to another .js file. In the HTML file I have a Jquery fancy box. When I open the Jquery fancy box. The initialized valriable is deleted why I do not know guys. please help with it.

JS:

```
function createEventDlg() {
      $.fancybox({
             href: "events/createEvent",
             type: "iframe", // <-- whatever content image, inline, swf, etc
             width: 600,
             afterClose: openEventImageUpdate
      });
   }
```

HTML:

```
<ul  class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                            <li class="li-search-logged">
                            <!-- id="selectedValueId" -->
                                <select  id="selectSearch">
                                    <option selected>Events</option>
                                    <option>Connections</option>
                                    <option>DFA Users</option>
                                </select>
                                <input type="text" id="auto-complete-tag" class="form-control" placeholder="Find Events, People, and Connections" />
                                <button class="btn btn-positive" type="button"></button>
                            </li>
                            <li class="li-btn"><input type="button" value="Create" class="btn btn-positive" onclick='createEventDlg();' /></li>
                            <li class="li-btn"><input type="button" value="Browse" class="btn btn-positive" onclick="loadBrowseEventPage()" /></li>
                            <li class="li-btn"><input type="button" value="DFA" class="btn btn-positive" onclick="loadDFA()" /></li>
                        </ul>
```

Browse.js:

Here appRootUrl variable has a value. Ex : "/app" and It calls a method in notifications. js's init() method. Then Notifications.js's object get initialized. My problem is When I open jquery fancy box. The initialized variable value is deleted Why I do not know. I will use this variable value for Jquery ajax call. because I have many methods in notifications.js. Those methods will use that variable value. please help me.

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
  <%
 ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
  Properties properties = new Properties();
  properties.load(classLoader.getResourceAsStream("app.properties"));
  %>
  var te = '${appRootUrl}';
  console.log('App root ulr : ' + te);
  notifications.init('${appRootUrl}', "<%= properties.getProperty("node.server")%>");    
});
```

Notifications.js:

```
var notifications = {
    appRootUrl : "something",
    nodeServer : "something",
    resource: {
        user: {
            findById: "/users/findbyid",
            getAlerts: "/users/getalerts",
            acceptChat: "/users/acceptchatinvite",
            declineChat: "/users/declinechatinvite",
            acceptFriend: "/users/acceptconnectioninvite",
            declineFriend: "/users/declineconnectioninvite",
            clearAlert: "/users/clearAlert",
            get: "/users/getuser",
            getEventPrivateChatHistory: "/users/eventPrivateChatHistory",
            eventPrivateSend: "/users/eventPrivatesend",
            dfaSend: "/users/dfasend",
            eventRestart: "/users/eventrestart",
            getFriendState: "/users/getFriendState",
            getDfaHistory: "/users/dfahistory",
            makeUserRelationshipNone: "/users/makerelationshipnone"
        },
        event: {
            getEventApprovedUsers: "/events/getApprovedUsers",
            getDfaGroupChatHistory: "/events/getGroupchatHistory",
            updateGroupChatMsgUrl: "/events/saveGroupchat",
            get: "/events/getEvent"
        }
    },
    init: undefined
};

notifications.init = function (appRootUrl, nodeServer) {
    console.log('appRootUrl : ' + appRootUrl);
    console.log('nodeServer : ' + nodeServer);

    notifications.appRootUrl = appRootUrl;
    notifications.nodeServer = nodeServer;
    console.log('notifications : ' + JSON.stringify(notifications));
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figured out the answer is I have to initialize the value from Jquery fancy box. Because The Jquery fancy box acts as a current JSP. Before It was initialized from browse.jsp. When The user clicks Jquery fancy box. It loads an JqueryFancyBox.JSP file. There I have to initialize the value.

The example code is here:

JqueryFancyBox.jsp:

```
<c:url var="appRootUrl" value="/"/>
$(function () {
            <%
            ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.load(classLoader.getResourceAsStream("app.properties"));
            %>
            notifications.init("${appRootUrl}", "<%= properties.getProperty("node.server")%>");
});
```